Statechart transition rate: Number is not matching with actual rate
I have Person agent (with 1000 people) in main. In the Person agent, I have a simple statechart with a transition from state to state1 with a rate. Please help me to understand, how this rate actually work.I have people set in GIS space. I have set a transition rate is as 5 per minutes. when I run the model, I can see the run time in the right-top corner. I found when the simulation run time is 5 minutes, there are way more than 25 people been transited. Why it happens?

Felipe explains it well, see below. But you can also read it in the help in detail: https://anylogic.help/anylogic/statecharts/transition.html#rate (they could make it more obvious in the IDE though, I agree)

The rate is not an exact thing. Using a rate generate a statistical arrival event following a poisson distribution. This means that every time you run a simulation (as long as you use a different seed) the number will be different in those 5 minutes. By default, anylogic uses a fixed seed, so you might see 35 transitions in the first 5 minutes, which is not wrong... If you run the simulation for very long, you will get an average of 5/minute
